# Can't make powershell use specified connection string for invoke-sqlcmd

Tags: sql, powershell, ssms

Ive managed to create a connection string which uses read only a connection but what I can't get to work is using that string in the invoke-SQLCMD

```
   $conn = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection
$ConnectionString = "Server=AIAZEFMXXXXX,6295;Database=XXX;Application Name=Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout={3};ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly" -f $ServerInstance,$Database,$ApplicationName,$ConnectionTimeout
$conn.ConnectionString=$ConnectionString
$conn.Open()


$Gate = (Invoke-Sqlcmd -ConnectionString $ConnectionString -Query "
          
            Declare @CDAy varchar(20) =datename(dw,Getutcdate())
            ,@CHour int =  datepart(Hour,Getutcdate())

            Declare @Gate int  =  (

                        Select AT.Gate as TC

                        From [dbo].[AcquirerAlertThreshold] as AT
                        Where AT.Day = @Cday
                        and AT.Hour =@CHour
                   );

            IF @Gate IS NULL 
                BEGIN

                Select @Gate = 5
               ENd; 
    
"|Select -ExpandProperty  TC
)
```

Comment: The minimum you need is following : $ConnectionString = "Server=AIAZEFMSQL03PRD;Initial Database=CKE;Integrated Security=True"  Try first connecting with SQL Server Management Studio.  The login window should show Window Credential and the Server\Instance.  Make sure the above connection string is exactly the same server\instance as connection string.  Port number is only required if it is not the standard port number 1433.  if you still fail check with SSMS explorer under management and see log files with login error.

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error the following worked for me

$SQLServer = "XXXX,XXX"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "Select count(*) as tc From customer " -ConnectionString "Data Source=$SQLServer;Initial Catalog="DBname";Integrated Security=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly"